# Custom namespace vs. null namespace: Android best practice

Tags: android, android-layout, namespaces, android-linearlayout, xml-namespaces

When developing Android user interfaces, should I define custom namespaces or use null namespaces? And why?

As a concrete example. Consider the following:

**Custom namespaces**

layout/main.xml:

```
<com.example.MyExample
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    custom:customString="Test String"/>
```

res/attrs.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyExample">
    <attr name="customString" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

src/com/example/MyExample.java:

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_example, this, true);   
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview)).setText(
    attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example", "customString")
);
```

**Null namespaces**

layout/main.xml:

```
<com.example.MyExample
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    customString="Test String"/>
```

src/com/example/MyExample.java:

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_example, this, true);   
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview)).setText(
    attrs.getAttributeValue(null, "customString")
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom namespaces are necessary if you have more than one library project with the same attribute names. Or if you are writing a library project you should use them in case somebody else is using same named atrributes. Otherwise it is up to you but recommended.